# Is it OK to use set-timeout for implement timer in turn based multiplayer game while using Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, settimeout, real-time-multiplayer

I am developing a 4 player turn-based multiplayer game using firebase as a backend and Unity as a front end. I Would like to give 20 sec for each player to move his turn. otherwise, the cloud function wants to move a random move for that player. that's why I write an **X-function** and call it with set-timeout after every move made player.

**X-function:** this function will check the player moved or not and if the player not moved, then choose a random move.

but the issue in the [firebase cloud function is the maximum value for time out is 540 sec.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions) if some of the players continually not moving then it will take more than 540sec. so that cloud-function is suspended.

can you suggest a better way to manage the timer for a turn-based player?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a function periodically with a short delay, you will be better off triggering that through [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks).  You will need to write logic to continually schedule a task (in the future) at the required period to trigger the function, and stop when it's no longer necessary.

Comment: No. I want only when the player is playing the game and independently. not like a schedule. i want to check exactly 20 sec after player moved.

Comment: Yes, you do want this.  If the player closes the app, the game will get stuck.  The delay logic should be controlled on the backend so the player can't interrupt it.

Comment: player not interrupting. the cloud-function suspended because of  timeout (when reaching 540 sec)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: ok. backend function maybe wants to call the `setTimeout( X-function() , 20000);` more than 30 time recursively. so this time takes nearly more than 600 sec. but the cloud function runs only 540sec. that's my issue.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm saying that Cloud Tasks is better suited to the job of scheduling items of work for future execution.  And probably cheaper than letting a function run without doing anything for some timeout.

Comment: @SajeevanVinayakavaseerakan why can't you just set a single timeout that takes 20 seconds? Then the timeout checks all the players to see if they submitted an answer, and if any player has not, then it can backfill an empty answer for them. Vs setting a timeout recursively? Not sure why you'd have to do that.